# how to add string to a specific line of file

Tags: php

my code is,

```
<?php 

$data = file_get_contents('file.conf');
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
$rcount = count($rows); 
echo $rcount;
for ($l=0; $l<$rcount; $l++)
{
    $rowss = $rows[$l];
    if ($rowss == "[default]")
    {
        file_put_contents($rowss, "\nhi", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX) or die("<br>oops");
    }
}


?>
```

output is,

```
52
oops
```

and my file(file.conf) contains 52 rows that is printed successfully,
but cant write on that file

i need to add some string like "hi" to the end of "[default]" line

example, my file is

```
eastern=America/New_York|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central=America/Chicago|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central24=America/Chicago|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours'
military=Zulu|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours' 'phonetic/z_p'
european=Europe/Copenhagen|'vm-received' a d b 'digits/at' HM



[default]

1234 => 4242,Example Mailbox,root@localhost
;4200 => 9855,Mark Spencer,markster@linux-    support.net,mypager@digium.com,attach=no|serveremail=myaddy@digium.com|tz=central|maxmsg=    10
;4300 => 3456,Ben Rigas,ben@american-computer.net
;4310 => -5432,Sales,sales@marko.net
```

pls help me

thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you want to add 2 lines after line 20.

You can use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$newlines = [ 'first line', 'second line' ];
array_splice($rows, 20, 0, $newlines);
```

The `$newlines` array can contain as many lines as you want to add. You can also just add one line, but it has to be in an array so that `array_splice` can use it.

So in your example you could use:

```
if ($rowss == "[default]")
{
    $newlines = [ 'first line', 'second line' ];
    array_splice($rows, $l + 1, 0, $newlines);
}
```

This will get the line with `[default]`, and add the lines after it (`$l + 1` is the current line, containing `[default]`).